# Jenkins pipeline stuck forever after triggering another build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins pipeline (main-pipeline) which triggers another build in one stage.

```
stage('Functional Testing') { 
  when {
      branch 'master'
  }
  steps {
    build 'another-pipeline'
  }
}
```

Main pipeline is stuck forever with following message on the console

```
13:27:20  Scheduling project: another-pipeline
13:27:20  sh: line 1: 125914 Terminated              sleep 3
```

When I check another-pipeline, I found that it was triggered and completed successfully. It was explicitly mentioned in another-pipeline log that

```
Started by upstream project "main-pipeline/master" build number 18
```

But main-pipeline/master 18 build is stuck forever with above error.

Please help me. I am stuck on this issue for around a week now.
I have tried building main pipeline multiple times but getting the same behavior again and again.

Please let me know if need to add more information.

Comment: Have you tried an echo after your the build command so you can be sure that your pipeline is finishing the build-step?

Comment: @mkemmerz I can see from pipeline view that stage("Functional Testing") is not finished though the build triggered for "another-pipeline" has finished. 
Please let me know if you need more information.